# Recover an overwritten file

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery

I had a linux plain text document file with close to 100000 lines, a size of 10 Mb. I accidentally overwrote the file via python code. But I got an exception in the middle of the code and think the file socket did not get closed properly. The new file has a few new lines (250) ,BUT the size of the file corresponds to the old one. 
I was wondering if the old content will still be there within the file and any chances of recovering the same. I tried using TestDisk and poked around a little bit. But it did not have any option for working on a particular file or maybe I am doing it wrong. I dont have any expertise in file systems and would really appreciate any pointers on how to proceed.
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the file still in use (opened by other application)

Try these steps

- Identify PID of the application that is still using the file by `lsof <fielname>`, let's say 12345 for example
- Go to /proc/12345/fd
  directory, hopefully you see a link that links to the file you want
- Try to copy it to another location

Comment: No, It is not used by any other application. Thanks anyway!